# Laravel schema column

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make numeric column in my table but I'm not sure which option would be the best fit for my need

## logic

1. numbers start from 4 figure up `e.g. 1000`
2. no ending limitation `can goes up like: 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999`
3. increased incrementally `e.g. last number was 1000, next will be 1001 (not random numbers)`

## Question

Laravel provided several option that can do my job but I need help to know which is the best for my purpose

1. bigIncrements
2. bigInteger
3. unsignedBigInteger

ALSO there is one option `->autoIncrement()` should I add that too?

Comment: no ending limitation makes the thing more complicated other wise bigInteger is one of good choice

Comment: Will you *actually* ever have numbers like `999999999999999999999999999999999999999999`? In Postgres, `bigInteger` has a limit of [9223372036854775807](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html)

Comment: thanks, and should i add `->autoIncrement()` to bigInteger column?

Comment: As @ceejayoz said, practically your count might not go up to that limit and you can use string or something like that to achieve your requirement , can you explain the basic purpose and usage of that column so that it's easy to understand

Comment: @SagarGautam the purpose is to specifying data by numbers, something like news websites they say `news #8665677` so you can report etc. more easy like that .

Comment: @mafortis You can only have one `autoIncrement` column. It's typically used for the auto-incrementing model ID. Your questions are unanswerable because you haven't told us much about what the data *does*. An `autoIncrement` on a bank balance would mean every new user would have an extra $1 from the last person's balance - not a good idea!

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks man, just before your comment i explained the purpose please see if you have idea

Comment: Purpose is just to distinguish the news then you can use uniqid() php function or some random unique string

Comment: If you want it to auto increment you should use `$table->bigIncrements('id');` it'll make it auto increment and make it unsigned. An unsigned integer will grow much larger than signed: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html

Comment: @SagarGautam so i make table `bigInteger` and in my controller use `uniqueId(),` ? thats what you mean?

Comment: @jsonArray so you say i change my `id` column or is just as sample? :)

Comment: @mafortis it's just a sample, name it whatever you need it to be.